# Reduce backup creation time

Tags: postgresql, backup

I will be performing a postgres upgrade from 11.5 to 12.5 that will affect production environment. The first step assumes, that the most recent backup of database was taken, before upgrading - we would like to reduce time of this stage, due to performing upgrade in night hours. After unsuccessful research I would like to as if taking a backup made few hours before exact upgrade backup will reduce the time of next backup procedure?

Comment: "snapshot" has a meaning in PostgreSQL which differs from what you use here.  Are you talking about a file-system snapshot?  Or a PostgreSQL backup? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, actually I ment database backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you take the backup.

If you use `pg_dump` or `pg_basebackup`, the backup time is not influenced by how long ago the previous backup was taken.

If you backup with `pg_basebackup` or another online file system backup technique, you don't need a new backup. Just use the previous one and the WAL archives, and you can restore any point in time in the life of the database.